# Наследование методов в java (android)

Tags: наследование, android, java

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста ответ на простой вопрос!=)
Есть класс 1 , есть класс 2 .
Класс 2 наследует класс 1 и все его методы, все тип топ. Но есть методы ,которые нужно наследовать классу 2 и их нет в классе 1...но наследовать в java можно только 1 класс...подскажите пожалуйста как быть?

Например в С++ можно было создать .h и там все прописать и include его куда захочешь, а тут я что-то понять не могу,читал много всего, но конкретный ответ не нашел.=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быть может стоит просто написать их в классе_2? Если будут нужны методы класса_1 и дописанные метода класса_2, то создайте класс_3 - потомок класса_2.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Что-то я туплю,действительно,оценив количество наследуемых классов, пришел к выводу,что нужно содать всего 2 класса 3 что бы не нужно было ничего дублировать.Просто такая проблема остро встает из-за сторонних классов из других библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

в java нету множественного наследования, сделано это специально дабы убить сразу кучу геморроя из c\c++.

вместо множественного наследования используются интерфейсы.